# How to get Vue to remove whitespace in compiled output?

Tags: vue.js

The preserve whitespace option in Vue isn't working. It is generating code with lots of whitespace:

```
                _vm._v(
                  "\n        " +
                    _vm._s(_vm.object.created_by_full_name) +
                    "\n      "
                )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following in vue.config.js

```
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .loader('vue-loader')
      .tap(options => {
        // modify the options...
        options.compilerOptions = { whitespace: 'condense' };
        return options;
      });
  },
```